# How to ensure registration form is unique for each user rather than the same username or email or address etc?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want my registration form to make sure that if the username already exists in my local storage, the user will not be able to register unless they change their username to something that hasn't been taken. Any ideas? I have already done nearly everything but just that part im stuck on.

Comment: localStorage is local to the individual browser, you understand that, right

Comment: basics are simple....check to see if it already exists in stored data before adding to collection. Can use any number of array iteration/filtering methods to do it

Comment: For starters write a simple `for` loop....go through data array and compare to values of that property. Can use other array methods also like `find()`, `some()` , `filter()` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before storing the details to your database, run a query to check if username exists in the database. First, the query should be directed only to the username row, then use a loop to check if the newly inputed username is in the database. If it is, just tell the user to change username.